# Ignoring past css

Tags: css

I want to have some images within a CSS container yet for them not to take the formatting of the container.
The effect I'm looking for is a background of one image and then these other images on top of it.

The big problem is for my main container I have

```
    border-radius:50px;
```

To create a nice rounded background image.
I don't want my inside images to be round however.

I try

```
div.innerimage img{ 
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

to do away with this however they stay round.
How do I stop this previous formatting being inherited?

Comment: I am not sure what you wnat but Css3 have something for set multiple image on a element. If you not want to take formating from inherited element then set their property too to fix this requirement

Comment: can you write down the html please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `!important`

```
div.innerimage img{ 
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes @sscirrus  you are correct. but some critical situation, we must use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need bring img outside div container which you have already set border-radius

for example:

```
<div class="containter">
    <div class="bgimage"></div>
    <img src="you_image_path" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.containter{position:relative;height: 100px;width:100px}
.bgimage{position: absolute; width: 100px;height:100px;top:0;left:0}
.containter img{position: absolute; width: 100px;height:100px;top:0;left:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

this example works fine
http://jsfiddle.net/YMr5y/1/

```
<div>   
<img width="100" height="100">
<div class="innerimage">
     <img width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

```
div img
{
border-radius:50px;
background-color:black;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
div.innerimage img{ 
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

I need your html to guess the real problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the style of parent element.

```
#container img {
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:10px;
}
#container .innerimage img {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

I guess you have html something like I have created on [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerdeepti/UezcC/1/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this is to attach a CSS class or ID to your background element, and attach the `border-radius` to that class.

Then, if you need to specify `border-radius:0` to your inner element, it will take precedence without any need for `!important`.